# Remove a block in preprocess

Tags: 6, hooks, blocks

I'm working on a Drupal 6 site made by other people, and I need to remove some block on the homepage for my language only.

I'm trying to use a [Context](http://www.drupal.org/project/context) and, by use of `hook_context_init()`, check if the context is active and remove the undesired blocks.

But i have a problem: How can I remove block in a hook function?

I hope my question is clear.

I don't want to hide the blocks with CSS because of the dirty markup..

[RESOLVED]
I did a preprocess like:

```
function wfp_homepage_context_preprocess_block(&$vars, $hook) {
    $to_delete = array('block_delta_1', 'block_delta_2')


    if(in_array($vars['block']->delta , $to_delete)){
        $vars['template_files'][0] = 'block-empty'; 
    }
}
```

and i add an empty block-empty.tpl.php in my theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SOLVED] I did a preprocess like:

```
function module_preprocess_block(&$vars, $hook) {
    $to_delete = array('block_delta_1', 'block_delta_2')
    if(in_array($vars['block']->delta , $to_delete)){
        $vars['template_files'][0] = 'block-empty'; 
    }
    }
```

and i add an empty block-empty.tpl.php in my theme.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`hook_page_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_page_alter/7) to do this. For example, if you wanted to remove the system navigation block from the "sidebar_first" region, you would do something like this:

```
function MYMODULE_page_alter(&$page) {
  if ($my_condition) {
    $region_name = 'sidebar_first';
    $block_name = 'system_navigation';

    if (isset($page[$region_name][$block_name])) {
      $page[$region_name][$block_name]['#access'] = FALSE;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but i forgot to say i'm using drupal 6 not drupal 7 
T______T
So i can't use the hook_page_alter().. any other ideas?

Comment: I'd like to do this in Drupal 8. Any pointers as to how? That hook was removed.

Answer (score 0):

The hook you're looking for is [`hook_block_view_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_alter/7), or it's [delta cousin](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_MODULE_DELTA_alter/7).

You'd check against `$module['delta']` to see if it's the block you care about, and then unset the subject and content of `$block`.

Comment: I'm working on Drupal 6 and hook_block_view_alter() is a drupal 7+ function..

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be an easy way to do this in D6. You if you are using the i18n internationalization module, you could define your paths, that are prepended with your language code, as exceptons in the block config menu. so something like es/* for spanish.

Haven't tested myself, just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

from Drupal8, an example of not displaying 2 blocks on 404 page:

```
 //exemple of condition
 $route_name = \Drupal::request()->attributes->get('_route');
 if ('system.404' === $route_name) {
    $region_name = 'content';
    $block_names = ['oneBlockID', 'andAnother'];
    foreach ($block_names as $block_name)
    if (isset($variables['page'][$region_name][$block_name])) {
      $variables['page'][$region_name][$block_name]['#access'] = FALSE;
    }
  }
```